# Disable java update popup “Your Java Version is out of date” on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, java

I want to disable Java update on Linux OS, I'm using Oracle Java and tried to disable update check from "Java Control Panel" but control panel doesn't have "Update" tab as windows Java control panel does. Is there any other way around?

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

I installed as:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: What oracle java version are you using and how did you install it?

Comment: That is weird. There shouldn't be any "Java Update" running. Is this popup coming from the browser? If so, which browser and does it only happen when you visit certain sites?